# How to prove a tighter bound $|\lambda_3-1| \leq \epsilon^2$ for an eigenvalue of $A$ with Gerschgorin's theorem and similar matrices?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization

Given the following matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
8 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 4 & \epsilon\\
0 & \epsilon & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, |\epsilon| < 1.$$
Gerschgorin's theorem states that each of the $\lambda_i$ eigenvalues of A will be placed inside a circular disk with center $a_{i,i}$ and radius $\sum^n_{j = 1, j\neq i} |a_{i,j}|$. As a direct consequence,  the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda_3$ of A is such that $|\lambda_3 -1| < \epsilon$.

However I'm now asked to prove the tighter bound $|\lambda_3-1| < \epsilon^2$ using diagonal similarity transformations. My initial idea was to use the first step of the QR algorithm for Hessemberg diagonalization as usual to obtain a similar matrix $A_1 = Q^*AQ$ (with $Q$ computed by Householder transformations) preserving the eigenvalues and hopefully the tighter bound appears using Gerschgorin's theorem once again. I've made some numerical tests using Octave for some particular $\epsilon$ and it seems to be indeed the case that $A_1$ satisfies the bound. The problem is that the exact computation of $Q$ and $A_1$ have been absolutely painful, specially when dealing with the unknown symbol $\epsilon$. I also tried to use a shift of $\rho = 1$ with no better results. So now I'm suspicious there is a simpler similarity transformation that could lead to the desired result. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at this thread  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517040/gershgorin-circle-theorem-and-similarity-transformations/  ?  you problem is similar but a bit easier I think.  *Hint:* as in that problem try to effect a similarity transform with a well chosen diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: I didn't check that thread before. That's a great tip, thanks! I will definitely try this solution format in my problem.

Comment: if you get an answer please post it below as an "answer" as I think it's within reach.  If not, I can post the answer later today though you may be annoyed at how simple it is -- once you 'see' it

Comment: Oh I think I finally got it, thank you very much! I can post my solution a bit latter today. You are right, it's not much of a complex problem after all, I've just over-complicated some of my attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract off the identity matrix so the upper left term is now $7.$ The characteristic polynomial is now
$$ x^3 - 10 x^2 + (20 -\epsilon^2)x + 7 \epsilon^2  $$

We wish to show that this has a root near zero, between $- \epsilon^2$ and $\epsilon^2.$  I guess we take $\epsilon \neq 0$ and treat that as a separate case.

The value of the characteristic polynomial when $x = \epsilon^2$ is
$$ \epsilon^2 \left( 27 - 11 \epsilon^2 + \epsilon^4 \right)  $$
which is positive, as $\epsilon^2 < 1.$

The value of the characteristic polynomial when $x = - \epsilon^2$ is
$$ -\epsilon^2 \left( 13 +9 \epsilon^2 + \epsilon^4 \right)  $$
which is negative, as $\epsilon^2 < 1.$

Te characteristic polynomial is continuous in $x,$ thus it has a root with
$$ - \epsilon^2 < x < \epsilon^2 $$

The original matrix has an eigenvalue $x$ with
$$ 1- \epsilon^2 < x < 1 +\epsilon^2 $$

ADDED: As **Robert** points out, we can simply evaluate the shifted characteristic polynomial $ x^3 - 10 x^2 + (20 -\epsilon^2)x + 7 \epsilon^2  $   at $x = t \epsilon^2,$ with $t$ real.  When $t=0$ we get (positive) $7 \epsilon^2.$ There is some cancellation available if we take $t = -\frac{7}{20},$ and the polynomial comes out as $$ \epsilon^2 \left( - \frac{350}{400} \epsilon^2 - \frac{343}{8000} \epsilon^4\right)  $$
which is negative. Thus the shifted eigenvalue is between $-\frac{7}{20} \epsilon^2$ and $0,$ the original eigenvalue between $1-\frac{7}{20} \epsilon^2$ and $1.$

Comment: In fact, we can push this a bit to show the matrix has an eigenvalue between $1- \frac{7}{20} \epsilon^2$ and $1$ for all real $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

One of the purposes of the question was to apply similarity transformations (which preserves eigenvalues) and Gerschgorin's theorem, so I'm posting an alternative to the accepted answer. As suggested by @user8675309, the problem may also be solved using a similarity transformation $A \mapsto D^{-1}AD$ with $D$ being a diagonal matrix.

If we let $c$ be a free parameter in $D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & c\\
\end{bmatrix}$, then $D^{-1}AD = \begin{bmatrix}
8 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 4 & c\epsilon\\
0 & \frac{\epsilon}{c} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

To make the bound as requested, take $c = \epsilon^{-1}$ to get the 3 following Gerschgorin's theorem disks
$$D_1 = \{x \in \mathbb{C} : |x-8| \leq 1\}, 
    D_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{C} : |x-4| \leq 2\}, 
    D_3 = \{x \in \mathbb{C} : |x-1| \leq \epsilon^2\}$$
Since they are disjoint under $|\epsilon| < 1$, each eigenvalue belongs to exactly one of this sets and therefore the lowest one is restricted to $|\lambda_3 - 1| \leq \epsilon^2.$